# How to generate all language version for given URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, internationalization

How to generate all language version for given URL

I have code in view:

```
- [:en, :de, :fr].each do |l|
  - I18n.locale = l
  = link_to l, category_path
```

I expected

```
/en/categories
/de/categorien
/fr/categorieu
```

On my page i have link to categories. If i change language on my page, link works perfect.

```
en >    /en/categories
de >    /de/categorien
fr >    /fr/categorieu
```

But I have only

```
/en/categories
/en/categories
/en/categories
```

How to do it well, to display  all localized path?

```
/en/categories
/de/categorien
/fr/categorieu

scope ':locale' do
  localized do
    resources :c, to: 'categories#show', as: :categories, only: :show
    resources :p, to: 'products#show', as: :products, only: :show do
      member do
        get :download
      end
    end
    resources :t, to: 'tags#show', as: :tags, only: :show

    resources :realizations, only: [:index, :show]
    resources :trusts, only: :index
  end
end
```

Regards

Comment: Show your `routes.rb` file

Comment: Can you please show where the category_path is defined. In `routes.rb`

Comment: Not sure if it works or not, but try `= link_to l, category_path(locale: l)`